# Issues with join the tables (6 tables)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to MySQL and also this is my first question if there is any mistakes please forgive me.

I have 6 tables i want to take report using this 6 tables. One of my report to access all the 6 tables and print the data as per the Query we write.Now the problem is i have write my query but this will return lot of duplicate data.How to avoid that guide me please.

Demo Data:

**add_employees**

```
 -------------------
 | eid | name      |                   
 -------------------
 | 1   | Mohanraj  |
 -------------------
 | 2   | pradeep   |
 -------------------
 | 3   | kumar     |
 -------------------
 | 4   | Murali    |
 -------------------
```

**add_vehicle**

```
 ---------------------
 | vid | vnumber     |                 
 ---------------------
 | 1   | TN22BQ6226  |
 ---------------------
 | 2   | TN37CM9014  |
 ---------------------
 | 3   | TN38BR9217  |
 ---------------------
 | 4   | TN38BT5680  |
 ---------------------
```

**third_table**

```
                 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 | tid | vid         | emp_id     | entry_date     | pick_place     | start_time     | drop_place     | stop_time     | pickupkm    | drops     | type_of_trip     | travelkm     | tamt     | dates     |                 
                 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 | 1   | TN22BQ6226  |  3         |    5-5-2017    |    Airport     |   03:15 am     |     ESI        |   06:30 am    |  10500      |   20500   |   Cash          |   10000        |  5000  |2017-05-05  |
                 | 2   | TN22BQ6226  |  3         |    6-5-2017    |    Hopes       |   09:44 am     |     ESI        |   12:30 pm    |  12500      |   2500   |   Cash          |   1250        |  3500  |2017-05-06  |
                 | 3   | TN22BQ6226  |  3         |    5-5-2017    |    Place1     |   03:15 pm     |     Place2        |   06:30 pm    |  1500      |   1800   |   Cash          |   300        |  1500  |2017-05-05  |
```

**fourth_table**

```
                    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     | fid | vid         | emp_id     | expcal     | exp1     | exp2     | exp3     | exp4     | exp5    | exp_amt     | exp_desc     | dates     |                    
                     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     | 1   | TN22BQ6226  |  3         |    100     |         |          |     100     |   100  |         |             |            | 2017-05-05   | 
                     | 2   | TN22BQ6226  |  3         |    50      |         |          |    50       |   50   |         |             |            |  2017-05-06   |
```

**five_table**

---

```
                     | fi_id | vid         | emp_id     | totkm     | totamt     | expenses     | today_balance     | handover_amt     | balance_amt    | handover_to     | plstatus     | entry_date     |     entry_time |               
                     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                     | 1   | TN22BQ6226     |  3         |    10000  |  5000    |   100       |     4900           |   4000             |    400       |     ram        |     PROFIT       | 2017-05-05   |    04:35:21 |
                     | 2   | TN22BQ6226     |  3         |    1250   |   3500   |     100     |    3400            |   3000             |    200       |    raj         |      PROFIT      |  2017-05-06   |   04:36:58  |
```

**shift**

```
                         ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         |  sid | emp_id | vid          | opeing_km     | opeing_cash     | closing_km     | closing_cash     | opeing_date     | opeing_time   | closing_date     | closing_time     | status     |               
                         ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         | 1   | 3      |  TN22BQ6226   |    0          |  0              |   10000       |     0           |   2017-05-05      |    04:32:17    |     2017-05-05    |    04:35:21      |  1       |
                         | 2   | 3      |  TN22BQ6226   |    20500      |   5000          |     1250      |     0           |   2017-05-06      |    04:34:55    |    2017-05-06     |     04:36:58     |  1       |
```

And i try this query i get wrong out,

```
SELECT a.vnumber
     , a.vname
     , b.eid
     , b.name
     , b.mobile
     , c.tid
     , c.vid
     , c.emp_id
     , c.pick_place
     , c.start_time
     , c.drop_place
     , c.stop_time
     , c.pickupkm
     , c.drops
     , c.type_of_trip
     , c.travelkm
     , c.tamt
     , c.dates
     , d.vid
     , d.emp_id
     , d.expcal
     , d.exp1
     , d.exp2
     , d.exp3
     , d.exp4
     , d.exp5
     , d.expamt
     , d.expdesc
     , d.dates
     , e.emp_id
     , e.vid
     , e.opeing_km
     , e.opeing_cash
     , e.closing_km
     , e.closing_cash
     , e.opeing_date
     , e.opeing_time
     , e.closing_date
     , e.closing_time
     , f.vid
     , f.emp_id
     , f.totkm
     , f.totamt
     , f.expenses
     , f.handover_amt
     , f.balance_amt
     , f.handover_to
     , f.plstatus
     , f.entry_date 
  FROM add_vehicle a 
  JOIN third_table c 
    ON a.vnumber = c.vid 
  JOIN add_employees b 
    ON b.eid = c.emp_id 
  JOIN fourth_table d 
    ON a.vnumber = d.vid 
  JOIN shift e 
    ON b.eid = e.emp_id 
  JOIN five_table f 
    ON a.vnumber = f.vid
     , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
 WHERE c.type_of_trip IS NOT NULL 
   AND c.dates BETWEEN '2017-05-05' AND '2017-06-05'  
   AND d.dates BETWEEN '2017-05-05' AND '2017-06-05' 
   AND f.entry_date BETWEEN '2017-05-05' AND '2017-06-05'
   AND c.vid = 'TN22BQ6226'
   AND f.vid = 'TN22BQ6226'
   AND e.vid = 'TN22BQ6226' 
 GROUP 
    BY c.tid 
 ORDER 
    BY c.dates
     , f.entry_date DESC
```

i get fourth_table and five_table values are repeated like this.
[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKwHc.png) and [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z0FE.png)

I want the output like this,

```
                         |  vnumber   |    vname          | eid          | name     |  tid     | vid          | emp_id     | pick_place   | start_time     | drop_place    | stop_time     |  pickup_km  | drops  | type_of_trip | travel_km | tamt |  dates           | vid          | emp_id |expcal |exp1 | exp2    | exp3 | exp4 | exp5 | expamt| expdesc | dates     | emp_id | vid         | opening_km | opening_cash |  closing_km | closing_cash | opeing_date | opeing_time | closing_date | closing_time | vid           | emp_id | totkm | totamt |     expenses |  handover_amt | balance_amt|  handover_to | plstatus | entry_date |     
                         -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         | TN22BQ6226   | Mahindra Logan  |     3        |    kumar  |  1      |   TN22BQ6226  |     3    |   Airport    |    03:15 am     |     ESI       |    06:30 am    |  10500     |  20500  | Cash        | 10000     |  5000|    2017-05-05    |   TN22BQ6226  |     3 | 100   |     |         | 100  | 100  |      |  100 |           |2017-05-05 |    3   | TN22BQ6226 |    0       |    0         | 10000       |      0       |  2017-05-05   | 04:32:17   | 2017-05-05 |  04:35:21     | TN22BQ6226     |     3  | 10000| 5000    |   100       |      4000      |     400   |   ram       |      PROFIT |   2017-05-05 |
                         | TN22BQ6226   | Mahindra Logan  |     3        |    kumar  |  2      |   TN22BQ6226  |     3    |   Hopes      |    09:44 am     |     ESI       |    12:01 pm    |  1250      |  2500   | Cash        | 1250      |  3500|    2017-05-06    |   TN22BQ6226  |     3 | 50    |     |         | 50   | 50   |      |  50  |           |2017-05-06 |    3   | TN22BQ6226 |    20500    |    5000    | 1250       |      0       |  2017-05-06   | 04:34:55   | 2017-05-06 |  04:36:58     | TN22BQ6226     |     3  | 1250| 3500    |   100       |      3400      |     200   |   raj       |      PROFIT |   2017-05-06 |
                         | TN22BQ6226   | Mahindra Logan  |     3        |    kumar  |  3      |   TN22BQ6226  |     3    |   place one  |    03:15 pm     |     place two |    06:15 pm    |  1500      |  1800   | Cash        | 300      |  1500|    2017-05-05    |   TN22BQ6226  |     3 | 100   |     |         | 100  | 100  |      |  100 |           |2017-05-05 |    3   | TN22BQ6226 |    0       |    0         | 10000       |      0       |  2017-05-05   | 04:32:17   | 2017-05-05 |  04:35:21     | TN22BQ6226     |     3  | 10000| 5000    |   100       |      4000      |     400   |   ram       |      PROFIT |   2017-05-05 |
```

sorry for big question.

Comment: Apology under consideration. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i create sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62f3e5      but i post this sqlfiddle some one ask text format so i spend an hours to make text format. sry @Strawberry

Comment: Thanks for the update. With a decent text editor, a copy-paste should take no more than 3 minutes.

Comment: oh god, it will take more then a hrs. totally waste my time. @Strawberry

Comment: some one help me to fix this problem

Comment: If it was me, I'd try to reduce the problem to its barest bones. Wading through some 50 columns isn't much fum for the reader.

Comment: Incidentally, columns like `d.exp5` are often symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: okaynow what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment...

Let's start by simplifying the problem as follows:

```
SELECT a.vid
     , d.emp_id
     , d.expcal
     , f.entry_date
     , f.entry_time
  FROM add_vehicle a 
  JOIN fourth_table d 
    ON d.vid =  a.vnumber
  JOIN five_table f 
    ON f.vid = a.vnumber 

vid emp_id expcal entry_date  entry_time
  1      3    100 2017-05-05    04:35:21
  1      3     50 2017-05-05    04:35:21
  1      3    100 2017-05-06    04:36:58
  1      3     50 2017-05-06    04:36:58
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62f3e5/21

Considering only the columns provided above, how does this differ from the desired result?

Incidentally - always store dates and times as a single entity

Comment: what about other columns and okay date and time in same field but here some time values are from time picker

Comment: The other columns seem irrelevant to the present problem, and time pickers are perfectly capable of providing dates and times as single entities.

Comment: i need a only one 50 and 100 why it will display twise?

Comment: Which 50, and which 100? There are two entry date times, so it shows both.

Comment: check fourth_table there is only one 50 and 100 aft joining we get as result two times